# Parse Facebook Post XML

Tags: xml, api, facebook, parsing, serialization

I need to parse XML sent y facebook after message is posted on web page.  XML is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<socialMediaMessage xmlns="http://www.test.com/SocialMediaLink" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <socialMediaSource>Facebook</socialMediaSource>
  <facebookMessage>
    <protocolVersion>1</protocolVersion>
    <direction>Inbound</direction>
    <inbound>
      <action>Event_NewComment</action>
      <event_NewComment>
        <uCIAccountName>altitude456@gmail.com</uCIAccountName>
        <pageProfile>
          <userId>853738988027292</userId>
          <name>Altitudetele</name>
          <email></email>
          <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/853738988027292</urlLink>
          <category>Telecommunication company</category>
          <nLikes>5</nLikes>
        </pageProfile>
        <newComment>
          <postId>853738988027292_162508306545581</postId>
          <commentId>162508306545581_673058007960935</commentId>
          <parentCommentId></parentCommentId>
          <fromProfile>
            <userId>6084755568286980</userId>
            <name>Dnyati Ganesan</name>
            <email></email>
            <urlLink></urlLink>
            <category></category>
            <nLikes>0</nLikes>
          </fromProfile>
          <message>hello</message>
          <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/159233336873078/posts/162508306545581</urlLink>
          <nLikes>0</nLikes>
          <createdTime>11/05/2023 02:59:28</createdTime>
        </newComment>
        <historical_post>
          <postId>853738988027292_162508306545581</postId>
          <fromProfile>
            <userId>853738988027292</userId>
            <name>Altitudetele</name>
            <email></email>
            <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/853738988027292</urlLink>
            <category>Telecommunication company</category>
            <nLikes>5</nLikes>
          </fromProfile>
          <message>test</message>
          <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/159233336873078/posts/162508306545581</urlLink>
          <attachmentName></attachmentName>
          <attachmentCaption></attachmentCaption>
          <attachmentLink></attachmentLink>
          <nLikes>0</nLikes>
          <createdTime>15/02/2023 16:32:20</createdTime>
          <updatedTime>11/05/2023 02:59:28</updatedTime>
        </historical_post>
        <historical_listComment>
          <comment>
            <postId>853738988027292_162508306545581</postId>
            <commentId>162508306545581_5945923735533933</commentId>
            <parentCommentId></parentCommentId>
            <fromProfile>
              <userId>5655483951137611</userId>
              <name>Prem Preet</name>
              <email></email>
              <urlLink></urlLink>
              <category></category>
              <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            </fromProfile>
            <message>Hi</message>
            <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/159233336873078/posts/162508306545581</urlLink>
            <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            <createdTime>05/05/2023 11:51:33</createdTime>
          </comment>
          <comment>
            <postId>853738988027292_162508306545581</postId>
            <commentId>162508306545581_1319403308608990</commentId>
            <parentCommentId></parentCommentId>
            <fromProfile>
              <userId>5838927156234053</userId>
              <name>Saurabh Roy</name>
              <email></email>
              <urlLink></urlLink>
              <category></category>
              <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            </fromProfile>
            <message>hi</message>
            <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/159233336873078/posts/162508306545581</urlLink>
            <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            <createdTime>05/05/2023 12:22:04</createdTime>
          </comment>
          <comment>
            <postId>853738988027292_162508306545581</postId>
            <commentId>162508306545581_1418183775615277</commentId>
            <parentCommentId></parentCommentId>
            <fromProfile>
              <userId>5838927156234053</userId>
              <name>Saurabh Roy</name>
              <email></email>
              <urlLink></urlLink>
              <category></category>
              <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            </fromProfile>
            <message>hi</message>
            <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/159233336873078/posts/162508306545581</urlLink>
            <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            <createdTime>05/05/2023 12:22:08</createdTime>
          </comment>
          <comment>
            <postId>853738988027292_162508306545581</postId>
            <commentId>162508306545581_950267632961220</commentId>
            <parentCommentId></parentCommentId>
            <fromProfile>
              <userId>5838927156234053</userId>
              <name>Saurabh Roy</name>
              <email></email>
              <urlLink></urlLink>
              <category></category>
              <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            </fromProfile>
            <message>hi</message>
            <urlLink>https://www.facebook.com/159233336873078/posts/162508306545581</urlLink>
            <nLikes>0</nLikes>
            <createdTime>05/05/2023 12:22:10</createdTime>
          </comment>
        </historical_listComment>
      </event_NewComment>
    </inbound>
  </facebookMessage>
</socialMediaMessage>
```

I tried below to deserialize the XML :

```
 public socialMediaMessage Deserialize<socialMediaMessage>(string input) where socialMediaMessage : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(socialMediaMessage), new XmlRootAttribute("socialMediaMessage"));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (socialMediaMessage)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }
```

it is giving me an exception as : System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (1, 2).'
InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.

my object is :

```
  [Serializable, XmlRoot("socialMediaMessage")]
    public class socialMediaMessage
    {
        public string socialMediaSource { get; set; }      
        public facebookMessage FacebookMessage { get; set; }
    }
    public class facebookMessage
    {
        public string protocolVersion { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
        public inbound Inbound { get; set; }
    }
    public class inbound
    {
        public string action { get; set; }
        public Event_NewComment event_NewComment { get; set; }
    }
    public class Event_NewComment

    {
        public string uCIAccountName { get; set; }
        public pageProfile PageProfile { get; set; }
        public newComment NewComment { get; set; }
        public historical_post historicalPost { get; set; }
        public historical_listComment historicalListComment { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class historical_listComment
    {
        public List<historicalComment> comment { get; set; }
    }
    public class historicalComment
    {
        public string postId { get; set; }
        public string commentId { get; set; }
        public string parentCommentId { get; set; }
        public pageProfile fromProfile { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
        public string createdTime { get; set; }
    }
    public class historical_post
    {
        public string postId { get; set; }
        public fromProfile fromProfile { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string attachmentName { get; set; }
        public string attachmentCaption { get; set; }
        public string attachmentLink   { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
        public string createdTime { get; set; }
        public string updatedTime { get; set; }
    }
    public class newComment
    {
        public string postId { get; set; }
        public string commentId { get; set; }
        public string parentCommentId { get; set; }
        public fromProfile fromProfile { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
        public string createdTime { get; set; }
    }

    //Page Profile & from profile structure is same
    public class pageProfile
    {
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public string profileName { get; set; }
        public string pageEmail { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
    }
    public class fromProfile
    {
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public string profileName { get; set; }
        public string pageEmail { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
    }
```

where could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the default namespace AND you property names have to match the xml tags exactly including uppercase/lowercase.  I made some changes below.  You need to fix the rest of the items

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(socialMediaMessage));
            socialMediaMessage message = (socialMediaMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
 
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.test.com/SocialMediaLink")]
    public class socialMediaMessage
    {
        public string socialMediaSource { get; set; }
        public facebookMessage facebookMessage { get; set; }
    }
    public class facebookMessage
    {
        public string protocolVersion { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
        public inbound inbound { get; set; }
    }
    public class inbound
    {
        public string action { get; set; }
        public Event_NewComment event_NewComment { get; set; }
    }
    public class Event_NewComment
    {
        public string uCIAccountName { get; set; }
        public pageProfile PageProfile { get; set; }
        public newComment NewComment { get; set; }
        public historical_post historical_post { get; set; }
        public historical_listComment historical_listComment { get; set; }
    }

    public class historical_listComment
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public List<historicalComment> comment { get; set; }
    }
    public class historicalComment
    {
        public string postId { get; set; }
        public string commentId { get; set; }
        public string parentCommentId { get; set; }
        public pageProfile fromProfile { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
        public string createdTime { get; set; }
    }
    public class historical_post
    {
        public string postId { get; set; }
        public fromProfile fromProfile { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string attachmentName { get; set; }
        public string attachmentCaption { get; set; }
        public string attachmentLink { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
        public string createdTime { get; set; }
        public string updatedTime { get; set; }
    }
    public class newComment
    {
        public string postId { get; set; }
        public string commentId { get; set; }
        public string parentCommentId { get; set; }
        public fromProfile fromProfile { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
        public string createdTime { get; set; }
    }

    //Page Profile & from profile structure is same
    public class pageProfile
    {
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public string profileName { get; set; }
        public string pageEmail { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
    }
    public class fromProfile
    {
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public string profileName { get; set; }
        public string pageEmail { get; set; }
        public string urlLink { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string nLikes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  as you said property names have to match the xml tags exactly including uppercase/lowercase I am facing issue in historical_listComment
 & comment tag is this is list of comment?

Comment: XmlSerializer with a List expect the xml to have to tags, your xml only has one.  So I added to the code [XmlElement] which will work with only one tag like in you xml